# Pull Mysql data remotely using Shell Script

Tags: mysql, shell

I have two servers A and B.

Mysql is installed on Server B. I want to run a shell script from server A which will do following things:

1. Login to server B.
2. Run a Mysql query (eg. show databases)
3. I want the output of above command in a txt file on server A.

Please help me in this. I am new in shell scripting.

Let me know if you need any future clarification

Comment: pls show us what you tried and what's not working in it.

Comment: I was trying this 

#!/bin/bash 
ssh root@172.16.210.190 && mysql -u root -ppass -e "show databases;" > /root/Desktop/new.txt 

I was running this script from Server A, Its creating a new.txt file on Server A at /root/Desktop/new.txt but its blank –

Comment: pls edit that into your question.

Answer (score 0):

With out pem file u can use the below code

```
#!/bin/sh

ssh username@remote mysqlshow -uroot -proot > /folder/databases.txt
scp username@remote:/folder/databases.txt /folder/
```

With pem file u can use the below code

```
#!/bin/sh

ssh -i filename.pem username@remote mysqlshow -uroot -proot > /folder/databases.txt
scp -i filename.pem username@remote:/folder/databases.txt /folder/
```

Comment: I was trying this

#!/bin/bash

ssh root@172.16.210.190 && mysql -u root -ppass -e "show databases;" > /root/Desktop/new.txt

I was running this script from Server A, Its creating a new.txt file on Server A at /root/Desktop/new.txt but its blank

Comment: your script is working
But it has given the complete output
<code>
`+--------------------+
|     Databases      |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| social             |
| test               |
+--------------------+`
<code>

I just want the names of databases

Comment: But this will only run for show databases. That was actually an example. I want a column from social database.